# Encountered array-valued parameter binding, but was expecting [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]

Tags: jpa, illegalargumentexception

```
@Query("SELECT adv FROM Advocacyadv where (adv.patient.facilityId IN (:facilityIds) or :facilityIds is null) "
            + " order by adv.createdDate desc ")
    public List<Advocacy> search(
            @Param("facilityIds") Integer[] facilityIds);
```

The above code gives the following error

**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Encountered array-valued parameter binding, but was expecting [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]**

My search may or may not have search parameters. If there are no search parameters, I want all the data to show up. If there are search parameters, I only need those that match. How can I accomplish this using JPA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a list

```
Query("SELECT adv FROM Advocacyadv where (adv.patient.facilityId IN (:facilityIds) or :facilityIds is null) "
            + " order by adv.createdDate desc ")
    public List<Advocacy> search(
            @Param("facilityIds") List<Integer> facilityIds);
```

Update:

The correct query is as follows:

```
Query(
    "SELECT adv FROM Advocacy adv " +
    "WHERE (:facilityIds IS NULL OR adv.patient.facilityId IN :facilityIds) " +
    "ORDER BY adv.createdDate DESC")
    public List<Advocacy> search(@Param("facilityIds") List<Integer> facilityIds);
```

1. If facilityIds is null it will return all Advocacys
2. If facilityIds is empty it will return an empty list
3. Otherwise it will return all Advocacys that have a patient with an id in facilityIds

Comment: This has resolved the IllegalArgumentException but now I get the following error "antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected end of subtree" followed by a NullPointerException. My guess is that's because the list is empty (not null because I create a new list with no items) when there are no search parameters. Wouldn't JPA be able to deal with the empty List with  :facilityIds is null? Should I execute a separate query when the list is empty? I thought the very purpose of "is null" was to allow for empty parameters and fetch everything if it was empty.

Comment: I tried doing the null before in that did not change the results. I still get "unexpected end of subtree) followed by NullPointerException.

Comment: The code I have pasted is working for me so beyond that I can't help you

Comment: Okay, I got it to work. I tweaked a little bit more than what you provided and that worked. Here's what I did - I manually made the list Null before passing it to the query. If the list is not null but empty, I get the error above. I also added a paranthesis around the :facilityIds. So the query now looks like Query(
    "SELECT adv FROM Advocacy adv " +
    "WHERE ((:facilityIds) IS NULL OR adv.patient.facilityId IN :facilityIds) " +
    "ORDER BY adv.createdDate DESC")
    public List<Advocacy> search(@Param("facilityIds") List<Integer> facilityIds); Thank you for helping me fix this!!

Comment: Glad you got it working